# SQL selected statement in Java

Tags: java, sql, database

I am trying to get a specific result from my database by executing a query with a passed in parameter. Currently it's saying the result set is empty, and I know it shouldn't be because there is a row in the database that meets the 'where clause'. So I'm thinking it's a problem with my query statement as this is the first time I've queried the database from Java.

Here's the code for the query:

```
public ResultSet getWordNetPathResultsFromDatabase(double result) throws SQLException {
    //System.out.println(words);
    Statement statement = conn.createStatement();

    ResultSet wordNetResults = statement.executeQuery("SELECT WORDNETRESULT FROM WORDNETSCORES WHERE LINRESULT = 'result'");

    return wordNetResults;
}
```

Comment: Empty is empty. If this is suspect, attach a debugger and inspect the ResultSet before it's used.

Comment: run the same query on command line client and verify the result.

Comment: Are you calling `ResultSet.next()` somewhere? Additionally you are comparing the value of the column `LINRESULT` with the string literal `'result'` not with the contents of the passed variable `result`. Read up on `PreparedStatement` to properly pass a parameter to a SQL statement: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

Comment: Besides the stated problem with the query string itself, doubles usually aren't safe to compare for equality; because floating-point values don't exactly represent decimal numbers, math on them can yield non-intuitive results - `.3 - .2` _might not_ equal `0 + .1`, for example.  Modern processors also have special hardware for the calculations, at a higher bit-count than would be stored, so the values can be subtly changed there, too.  What are you attempting to do here?

Answer (score 1):

Your **result** variable is a double-type. So no need for single quote in your query:

```
ResultSet wordNetResults = ("SELECT WORDNETRESULT FROM WORDNETSCORES WHERE LINRESULT = "+ result);
```

Comment: Actually the need for simple quotes depends on the type of the field in the database, not the variable used for constructing the query.

Comment: yes, is true but if in your java program, you define result double so think that in you database the type of column is something decimal

Comment: If you where querying a string what would the syntax be?

Answer (score 0):

As [esprittn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2123347/esprittn) mentioned, your query is supposed to return only those results where LINRESULT = result. Now, in your getWordNetPathResultsFromDatabase() function parameter, you have used result as a function parameter, and you have specified its data type as double. In your query, you are not actually trying to return a double value, but a string named 'result'. That's why it was creating confusions.

You can do any one of the following two things.

Either:

```
public ResultSet getWordNetPathResultsFromDatabase(double result) throws SQLException {
//System.out.println(words);
Statement statement = conn.createStatement();

ResultSet wordNetResults = statement.executeQuery("SELECT WORDNETRESULT FROM WORDNETSCORES WHERE LINRESULT = " + result);

return wordNetResults;
```

}

Here in order to return the result value using it inside your querystring, you must separate it from the query statement using a '+' sign. And this is the standard method.

Or if you want to return a string 'result', then you can do this:

```
public ResultSet getWordNetPathResultsFromDatabase(String s) throws SQLException {
//System.out.println(words);
Statement statement = conn.createStatement();

s = 'result';    

ResultSet wordNetResults = statement.executeQuery("SELECT WORDNETRESULT FROM WORDNETSCORES WHERE LINRESULT = " + s);

return wordNetResults;
```

}

Depends on what exactly do you want to achieve as result. Choice is yours.

Comment: Under no circumstances should he do this with a string input parameter - he'll be nicely open to SQL Injection.  There's no reason this shouldn't be a parameterized and prepared query in the first place, which may even make it faster.